# Console application, windows service, or web service for reading from Azure SQL database every 5 minutes?

Tags: c#, database, web-services, azure, windows-services

I want to have a method that checks table in Azure database every 5 minutes with no condition, so it's just a scheduled task that runs every 5 minutes regardless of anything.

Not sure what is the best application template I should use for this, I'm choosing between Console application, Windows service, Web service, or something else.

Please let me know which one will do the job better and will be easier for scheduling.

Comment: It just have to be running task every 5 minutes, or it has specific endpoint after check?

Comment: This should work in Azure SQL as well (untested) - https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency. It's a much better approach than blindly poking at the database. Do the work with either Azure Functions or WebJobs.

Comment: Actually it should keep checking Azure queue every 5 minutes, no trigger or stopping condition, it will just check the queue every 5 minutes and when there is new message it should call another method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run something in the cloud, consider using an Azure Logic App. You will probably want to check the database and then take some action based on the result of your query. With Logic Apps you can implement  a workflow using the designer. It requires minimal coding since various connectors are already available out of the box. Additionally you are charged only for the compute time during which the app is run. 
If you have some enhanced logic to execute you can consider writing an Azure Function and call it from the Logic App.

You say you want to periodically check a queue and perform some action if a message exists. You have 2 options

1. [Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) that is triggered whenever a new message arrives in the queue. It would be cheaper and easier to have your function called by Azure whenever a message arrives in the queue rather than continuously polling the queue every 5 minutes and check for a message.
   [image: QueueTrigger]
2. [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-what-are-logic-apps) that describes the workflow. Here you can easily configure which Queue to poll, perform checks on the message and use existing connectors to easily access the SQL table whenever your conditions are satisfied.

[image: Logic App]

Comment: Those options sounds very interesting, but can you please tell me what is the benefit of using those over using WebJobs? 
Also, my logic is whenever new message added to the queue, I should start different thread that runs every 2 minutes for 6 hours to keep checking values in Azure SQL database, so given this scenario, which application type will be the best?

Answer (score 1):

The best would be ConsoleApplication.

If you want to run it from your computer, just run it. If you want to run it in Azure - use Azure Web Jobs.

[image]

Create AppServie in Azure, then select this blade on the AppService page and follow instructions. These web jobs can run regular ConsoleApplications from Azure. Application can do whatever it wants.

Comment: Should I just build the project in "Release" mode, copy the .exe file somewhere and schedule task or Azure WebJob to run this exe file?

Comment: Release or debug, this does not matter. Azure does not know what is that. The exe file and other stuffs like dlls, app.config, etc will be picked up as part of the deploy process.